# rails 4.0 beta, fields_for not accepting more than one argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arguments, ruby-on-rails-4, fields-for

This works:

```
<%= f.fields_for :exercise do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'exercise_fields', f: builder %>
        <% end %>
        <%= add_fields "Add Exercise", f, :exercises %>

    <%= f.submit %>
```

but adding another argument (in this case a reference to the object) throws an ArgumentError:

```
<% @workout.exercises.each do |exercise| %>

        <%= f.fields_for :exercise, exercise do |builder| %>
            <%= render 'exercise_fields', f: builder %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <%= add_fields "Add Exercise", f, :exercises %>

    <%= f.submit %>
```

Error: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

I've seen this multiple times in different places. Is this a bug or am I making some simple mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass it as an array:

```
<%= f.fields_for [:exercise, exercise] do |builder| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Woops, it was of course a simple mistake. I was overriding the fields_for helper method in a custom form builder and I only defined it as having one argument.